# ruby registry checking

Tags: ruby, windows, registry

I have the following snippet which I am trying to use to validate registry keys (OS is Windows 2008R2 or Win7)

```
def value_exists?(path,key)
  reg_type = Win32::Registry::KEY_READ 
  Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open(path, reg_type) do |reg|
    begin
      regkey = reg[key]
      return true
    rescue
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

When I do the following 2 commands the output is expected (in my case false is returned) :

```
puts(value_exists?("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\",'PendingFileRenameOperations'))
puts(value_exists?("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Component Based Servicing\\",'RebootPending'))
```

When I perform a

```
puts(value_exists?("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate\\Auto Update\\",'RebootRequired'))
```

I get the following error

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:528:in `open': The system cannot find the file specified. (Win32::Registry::Error)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/win32/registry.rb:608:in `open'
        from ./reg2.rb:7:in `value_exists?'
        from ./reg2.rb:21
```

I don't really understand what to do to make this work.  I suspect it might have something to do with the systems being x64 and it failing to find the key in the right location.  but I am not sure what I need to do to remedy this.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: This might be a silly question, but did you `require 'win32/registry'`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx

reg_type = Win32::Registry::KEY_READ | 0x100

This solved the issue! My guess is that you guys were not testing on x64?

Comment: Yes! this makes it work with ruby 1.9.3 (x86) on Window x64, thank you!

Comment: If this worked for you, make sure you mark this as an answer.

Comment: what is the meaning of the pipe here?

Answer (score 1):

your issue is that following path `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate\\Auto Update\\` does not exist in your registry. Have you checked it using regedit?

You should modify your code to -

```
def value_exists?(path,key)
    reg_type = Win32::Registry::KEY_READ 
    begin
        Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open(path, reg_type) {|reg| regkey = reg[key]}
    rescue
        false
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not duplicate your issue on ruby 1.9.2 P286, three false are returned as expected even keys does not exist.

You can compare the source code under <ruby path>\lib\ruby\<version>\win32 to find out the change, and update by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using `ENV`. It acts as a hash, and allows you to do hash functions.

```
ENV.has_key?("CUSTOM_PATH") #=> Should return TRUE or FALSE
```

and to list all the available keys

```
ENV.each do |k, v|
    puts "#{k} is related to #{v}"
end
```

I hope that helps.

[Ruby-Doc Core-2.0.0 - ENV](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ENV.html)